# Tikz node centers with scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

Can you explain why TikZ places the node center incorrectly in this MWE? I expect the red node to overlap the black one entirely, but it does not. If I remove the scaling, the problem goes away.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-100,yscale=-100]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt,minimum size=2mm,draw=black,fill=black,circle]

    \node (A) at (2,2) {};
    \node at (A.center) [red] {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-100,yscale=-100,transform shape]` for more surprises.

Comment: I am not so good with tikz but aren't you placing the bottom left corner of the red node at the center of the black node?

Comment: @MatoBehr No, the coordinate you give it is the center of the node.

Comment: This seems to be caused by a rounding error when TikZ is scaling and retrieving the coordinates for the center of the node.  You can repeat this by writing `\node (B) at (A.center) [red] {};` and then create a node `C` etc.  Then examine the coordinates for the center of these nodes using:    `\foreach \myn in {A,B,C}
  {\pgfextractx\aex{\pgfpointanchor{\myn}{center}}
   \pgfextractx\aey{\pgfpointanchor{\myn}{center}}
   \typeout{==> \myn ==> [\the\aecm]\the\aex,\the\aey}}`
where `\aex`, `\aey`, and `\aecm` are lengths, and `\aecm` has length 1 cm.

Comment: The problem is just barely visible at scale=10, while scale=8 looks fine.

Comment: OK, rounding error makes sense to me. Glad I'm not just misunderstanding how the coordinates work. Seems like maybe the best option is for me to "pre-scale" the coordinates to the size/shape I need before putting them in tikz and then not use scaling in the tikz code.

Comment: @A.Ellett Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-100,yscale=-100]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt,minimum    size=2mm,draw=black,fill=black,circle]

\coordinate (a) at (2,2);
\node (A) at (a) {};
\node (B) at (a) [red] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```